# JWT token has expired - How to handle and generate a new token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm encountering an issue with JWT (JSON Web Token) authentication in my application. When making API requests, I sometimes receive the following error response:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "jwt expired"
}
```

I understand that this error occurs when the JWT token has expired. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to handle this situation and generate a new token. I have tried a lot to solve this problem, but it cannot solve it. I tried to logout and login again and again but still cannot solve this problem.

[image: JWTToken expire checker function]

I'm currently developing a web application for an ecommerce platform, and I have successfully implemented CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations for products. However, I'm facing a challenge related to user authentication and authorization. I want to ensure that only authenticated users who have logged into the website can create and delete the products they have listed. In other words, unauthorized users should not have access to these actions. I'm seeking a solution to implement this user-specific restriction while allowing authenticated users to perform the desired CRUD operations on their own products.

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as screenshots.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. Which one do you like?

First one would be to intercept the "jwt expired" error response by implement an error handling mechanism in your code to detect this specific error message and handle it accordingly.  You can also refresh the token upon receiving the "jwt expired" error, initiate a token refresh process. This typically involves sending a request to a designated endpoint on your server, along with the expired token. Also, you can implement server-side validation on the server-side, verify the expired token and the user's identity. If the token is indeed expired but the user is still authenticated, generate a new token.

Another way would be to issue a new token after successful server-side validation, generate a fresh JWT token for the user. This new token will have a refreshed expiration time, allowing the user to continue using the application without interruption.

Try update client-side storage as an alternative once you have the new token from the server, update the client-side storage (e.g., local storage or cookies) with the refreshed token. This ensures that subsequent API requests include the updated token for authentication.

You may also retry the failed request with the new token in hand, retry the failed API request that initially encountered the "jwt expired" error. Include the updated token in the request's authorization header to authenticate the user and proceed with the desired operation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).